# Regular expressions mathematicals for php

Tags: php

Anyone know any php library that knows how to interpret and operate like excell ? i search but not found,
i store this 'regular expressions ' in a fields in table from inputs:

```
field0 : client_id,
field1 : "x * 0´7 ",
field2 : "x +  0,7 ",
field3 : "if(x<500) then x * 0,5 else 100",
field4 : "0,5+0,5+..",
```

after i take x from a query of other tables and operate with the library for do a report

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.”_

Comment: With [phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can use excel expression